# How to close web browser window from code behind page after form post request completes, in razor web app using .netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post, razor-pages

I have a page on my razor app (EditMode.cshtml) that contains a form. When this form makes a post request to it's code behind page (EditMode.cshtml.cs), I'd like to close the page after the post request completes, from the codebehind page. Is there a way to do this?

I've looked on overflow and see a lot of MVC examples but I dont see any for razor web applications. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
//EditMode.cshtml.cs
public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            VthaForms test = VthaForm;
            List<VthaWorkflows> test2 = VthaFormWorkflows;
            return null; //I've tried inputting a couple MVC solutions here, but to no avail.
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to do some voodoo magic to get this to work:

```
//EditMode.cshtml
<script>
    $(function() {
        var ispostback = '@Model.IsPostBack';
        if (ispostback=='True') {
            window.close();
        }
   });
</script>

//EditMode.cshtml.cs
[BindProperty]
public bool IsPostBack { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    VthaForms test = VthaForm;
    List<VthaWorkflows> test2 = VthaFormWorkflows;
    IsPostBack = true; //set the binded model property here, before postback
    return Page();
}
```

still pretty new to razor .netcore, so i'm sorry if this question was trivial. Hopefully this can help someone else down the line. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Lol it's not voodoo it's just JavaScript. You can't close a browser from server-side code because the browser isn't running on the server, so the server has no control over it. So instead you use JavaScript which runs inside the browser. Fairly logical when you think about it...glad you figured out a solution.

Comment: appreciate the upvote my friend, and the nice explanation!